# Declaring a single justice procedure notice on UK work visa application

Tags: uk, working-visas, work-permit

I bought a car June this year and I became the registered keeper 2 weeks later. Later, I received a letter from dvla to tax or SORN the car. However, I left the car at the sellers custody to resell the car and he subsequently asked me to ignore the letter from dvla.

Recently I received a single justice procedure notice from dvla for keeping or using an unlicensed vehicle. I called dvla to inform them that I never used the car before it was sold, and I was asked to pay £97. DVLA later sent me a letter that the case has been withdrawn.

In this case, do I need to disclose this in my visa application?

Comment: This question seems to be better suited for Expatriates. It is not about travel.

Comment: Personally I would disclose it and provide a copy of the letter from the DVLA. But then I am fairly risk-averse.

Comment: What question on a UK visa application would prompt disclosure of a civil claim presented (and then abandoned) by a UK government agency?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica IIRC there’s a question about whether an applicant has ever received a traffic fine, or a caution, reprimand, warning, or other penalty. The £97 may have been an out of court settlement for keeping an untaxed vehicle https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/vehicle-enforcement-policy/dvla-enforcement-of-vehicle-tax-registration-and-insurance-offences for example, in which case it may well count as a ‘penalty’

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, the visa application question about convictions and penalties asks:

> At any time, have you ever had any of the following, in the UK or another country?

The sub questions include:

> - A criminal conviction
> - A penalty for a driving offence, for example disqualification for speeding
> - A caution, warning, reprimand or other out-of-court penalty

Vehicle tax / registration offences are classed as criminal offences in the UK [GOV.UK Vehicle enforcement policy](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/vehicle-enforcement-policy/dvla-enforcement-of-vehicle-tax-registration-and-insurance-offences). It appears you paid £97 as an out-of-court settlement alternative to possible prosecution.

So **yes** you should disclose this penalty in your application and provide the DVLA letter as evidence.